# Cabal says tests pass but in fact they fail?

Tags: haskell, cabal

When I run the test suite using `cabal test`, I got the following message:

```
Running 1 test suites...
Test suite tests: RUNNING...
Test suite tests: PASS
Test suite logged to: my-lib-tests.log
```

But when I looked at the log file, the content was:

```
Test suite tests: RUNNING...
*** Failed! Falsified (after 1 test):
[]
Test suite tests: PASS
Test suite logged to: my-lib-tests.log
```

Why did I get a pass message when the tests clearly failed?

Comment: More info please.

Comment: @leftaroundabout What info should I provide? I'm quite new to haskell and cabal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cabal test` works under the assumption that a failing test suite will exit with a non-zero error code.

`quickCheck` prints a counterexample but returns normally.

To make the test executable fail when a counterexample is found, you can wrap QuickCheck tests using [`quickCheckResult` and `isSuccess`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.14.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#v:quickCheckResult).

There are test frameworks that do this for you, with a lot of useful functionality on top (like command-line arguments to select the tests to run), like [`tasty`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tasty), with `tasty-quickcheck`.